# Using hypen as key name in dynamo db mapper

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: "-", near:foo-bar when the key name has hypen. I have tried using the with expression attribute names and attribute values but still i am getting the same error. How can i solve this issue?

```
Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: "-", near:
Map<String,String> eak = new HashMap<>();

        eak.put("#k","foo-bar");
Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<>();
eav.put(":v", new AttributeValue().withS("val"));
DynamoDBQueryExpression<J> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<J>()
                    .withKeyConditionExpression("#k = :v")
                    .withExpressionAttributeNames(eak)
                    .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav)
                    .withScanIndexForward(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot have a column containing a hyphen, `foo-bar`, while using it the `KeyConditionExpression`.

In your example, the `.withKeyConditionExpression("#k = :v")`
• is expended to `.f("foo-bar = val")`,
• which is similar to `.f("foo - bar = val")` (note the spaces around `-`).

**The `-` is no longer interpreted as a character in a column name, but as an operand.**
For obvious reasons, this will throw an error, because the `-` is not in an allowed position.